# PySpark: Get first Non-null value of each column in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm dealing with different Spark `DataFrames`, which have lot of Null values in many columns. I want to get **any one** non-null value from each of the column to see if that value can be converted to datetime.

I tried doing `df.na.drop().first()` in a hope that it'll drop all rows with any null value, and of the remaining `DataFrame`, I'll just get the first row with all non-null values. But many of the `DataFrames` have so many columns with lot of null values, that `df.na.drop()` returns empty `DataFrame`.

I also tried finding if any columns has all `null` values, so that I could simply drop that columns before trying the above approach, but that still not solved the problem. Any idea how can I accomplish this in efficient way, as this code will be run many times on huge `DataFrames`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `first` function with `ingorenulls`. Let's say data looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField

schema = StructType([
    StructField("x{}".format(i), StringType(), True) for i in range(3)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(None, "foo", "bar"), ("foo", None, "bar"), ("foo", "bar", None)],
    schema
)
```

You can:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

df.select([first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in df.columns]).first()
```

```
Row(x0='foo', x1='foo', x2='bar')
```

Comment: This didn't work. I got this error:
`TypeError: _() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignorenulls'
`

Comment: I'm using PySpark 1.6. `ignorenulls` is not available as an argument. Any workaround?